# Bare bones HTTP server for linux with resumable file downloads

Tags: linux, download, http, webserver, file-download

I have a Windows user I want to share a large file with, they have Firefox with I understand supports resumable HTTP file downloads, and I have Ubuntu Linux, but limited  disk space and such, so I don't want a full blown solution like Apache's web server.

I'd like to just run the server via the command line or GUI when I want, not on boot.

If I can avoid it, I don't want to edit a config file - I'd rather just give a command line argument for it's port, I'm used to using python -m SimpleHTTPServer - but I don't think it is resumable.

Comment: "share a ... file" - So... you want to transfer a file eh, and you don't want to use the FILE TRANSFER PROTOCOL why?

Comment: I don't find name-ism useful here, there is nothing wrong with wanting to use a browser to download a file especially since the end user is comfortable with it. Don't see what should be complex or problemabtic about running a resumable HTTP server, do you?

Comment: I have a partial answer I may post in ~6 hours (rep < 100):  http://pastebin.com/DS0wedwk

Comment: @todda.speot.is: maybe because FTP is insecure and sends password across the network.

Comment: Mainly it's because simplicity for end users is king.

Comment: @MaxMackie: There is *no difference* in security between anonymous FTP and standard HTTP; between plaintext-authenticated FTP and "Basic"-authenticated HTTP; between FTPS and HTTPS.

Comment: Except that anonymous FTP is likely to require reading help and anonymous HTTP is just standard. But yeah - SIMPLICITY is what I want and have found! Thanks everyone.

Comment: @grawity I was referring to using ssh

Comment: Hey guys if you're passionate about the question perhaps up voting it would help ensure others will learn too. Currently this question stands at 0. Thanks.

Comment: @Luke: All browsers have [anonymous FTP support](ftp://ftp.sunet.se/pub/) built in.

Comment: Grawity they may but that doesn't mean that end users are familiar with it. For a one way resumable sharing of a file, HTTP is simple, following the principle of least surprise.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use **thttpd**.

```
thttpd -d /home/bob/sharedfolder -p 8080
```

The directory `/home/bob/sharedfolder` would become accessible at `http://address:8080`.

[image: screenshot of thttpd directory listing in Chrome showing localhost on port 8080]

---

**lighttpd** can be used in a similar way, although it needs a *tiny* config file. For example:

```
server.document-root = "/home/bob/sharedfolder"
server.port          = 8080
dir-listing.activate = "enable"
```

which is then ran like this:

```
lighttpd -f foo.conf
```

Comment: Thanks grawity, I made some edits. Would appreciate some question upvotes.

Comment: even `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000` should be enough ... :)

Comment: @akira: `SimpleHTTPServer` does not support byte ranges, meaning it cannot resume interrupted transfers. Test with `curl http://localhost:8000/testfile -o /dev/null -C 100`, for example.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, using lighttpd now and it's working great.

Comment: @grawity: true. but that aside: might be a viable option. missing byte range: thats why i only put it aside your answer and not as a standalone answer.

Answer (score 4):

I recently created a python module, `ext_http_server`, that extends the functionality of the `SimpleHTTPServer`module. One of its features is resumable file downloads, in addition to https, authentication and rate limiting.

[Here](https://github.com/bboe/extended_http_server#installation)'s a direct link to the installation and usage instructions.

I should state that lighttpd contains all the same functionality so if you're looking for something production-ready go with lighttpd. If you're looking for using something in python that you can easily build-upon, check out `ext_http_server`.

Comment: that sounds cool!

Comment: I actually used this for something but I didn't want rate limiting, https or user/pass, so it's a bit verbose to command for what I wanted:
ext_http_server --cert /home/luke/Downloads/cert.pem -d . -p 9191 -a test:test -r 999999999999999

Comment: The default executable in the package that is created is meant to have all of those features. With a little work you could build your own executable (script) that has only the resumable downloads. However, in that case, it'll probably be faster to use thttpd or lighttpd.

Comment: Yeah, it might be worth considering a simple mode, or as a simple mode as a default. Nice work though, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/) - You're using Linux so I guess you're familiar with the drill!
Place the file you want to share in the /var/www folder
Modify the init.d conf file to remove [Lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/) from bootup daemons.

Lighttpd does all you want and more - And, its not small, its TINY! ;)

Comment: Yeah I used Monkey already. Arbitrary difference perhaps. See: http://pastebin.com/DS0wedwk
 but I'm looking for a 0 config file solution if possible :)

Comment: lighttpd doesn't seem to support byte ranges if I download a file with curl I get:
HTTP server doesn't seem to support byte ranges